# Android app - sqlite database issue on close

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating an Android app in Eclipse, and the section I am having issues with is where I am trying to populate a ListView with data from a SQLite database.

When I run the app and try to open this particular fragment, the app crashes. When I comment out the line `newDB.close()` on the 4th last line of BreakfastMenuFragment.java, it will load but the listview is not populated.

I have tried to find the issue but no luck, any help will be appreciated.

BreakfastMenuFragment.java

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BreakfastMenuFragment extends Fragment {

    public BreakfastMenuFragment(){}

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;
    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     * @return */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.menuList);

        try {
            openAndQueryDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        displayResultList(listView);        
return rootView;
    }
    private void displayResultList(ListView listView) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void openAndQueryDatabase() throws IOException {
        try {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT itemdesc, itemprice FROM " + tableName +  " WHERE menu LIKE 'Breakfast'", null);

            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String itemDesc = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("itemdesc"));
                        double itemPrice = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("itemprice"));
                        results.add("" + itemDesc + " - Price: £"+ itemPrice +"");
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }           
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
        } finally {
            if (newDB != null) 
                newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
                newDB.close();
        }
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public SQLiteDatabase DB;
    public String DBPath;
    public static String DBName = "orchard.sqlite";
    public static final int version = '1';
    public static Context currentContext;
    public static String tableName = "menuitems";


    public DBHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context, DBName, null, version);
        currentContext = context;
        DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
        createDatabase();
    }

    private void createDatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

        if (dbExists) {
            // do nothing
        } else {
                    // Open your local db as the input stream
                    String dbname = "orchard.sqlite";
                    InputStream myInput = currentContext.getAssets().open(dbname);
                    // Path to the just created empty db
                    String outFileName = currentContext.getFilesDir().getPath() + dbname;
                    // Open the empty db as the output stream
                    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
                    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    }
                    // Close the streams
                    myOutput.flush();
                    myOutput.close();
                    myInput.close();

                }   
            }       

    private boolean checkDbExists() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {

            // database does't exist yet.

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

-------------EDIT--------------------

```
04-25 03:00:31.485: D/dalvikvm(31817): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 147K, 15% free 3288K/3828K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
04-25 03:00:31.805: E/SQLiteLog(31817): (1) no such table: menuitems
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817): Could not create or Open the database
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: menuitems (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT itemdesc, itemprice FROM menuitems WHERE menu LIKE 'Breakfast'
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BreakfastMenuFragment.openAndQueryDatabase(BreakfastMenuFragment.java:72)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BreakfastMenuFragment.onCreateView(BreakfastMenuFragment.java:38)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
04-25 03:00:31.815: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/SQLiteLog(31817): (1) no such table: menuitems
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817): Could not create or Open the database
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: menuitems (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT itemdesc, itemprice FROM menuitems WHERE menu LIKE 'Breakfast'
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BreakfastMenuFragment.openAndQueryDatabase(BreakfastMenuFragment.java:72)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.BreakfastMenuFragment.onCreateView(BreakfastMenuFragment.java:38)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
04-25 03:05:53.795: E/BreakfastMenuFragment(31817):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have a couple questions regarding your issue.
1.  Why do you delete the contents of your table before you close the database?
2.  Where do you populate the contents of the table?

Comment: 1. That was a line I put in and forgot to remove! 2. The database is a file which is already populated, orchard.sqlite which is located in the project

Comment: Have you done a full uninstall of the app and reinstall since removing the line that deletes the contents of the table?  @rohn-adams solution should work after you remove the DELETE statement, but you will need to fully uninstall the app and then reinstall it so the fresh database gets created, otherwise you won't see anything because the table is empty.

Comment: I have added brackets around the newdb.close(), removed the line deleting the table, uninstalled the app and reinstalled it. The app no longer crashes but the listview will not populate now!

Comment: Please post your logcat output.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by adding 

File file = new File(myPath);    
if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory())

before the SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (newDB != null)
    newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);

newDB.close();
```

newDB.close(); is executing regardless of whether it is null or not. This would likely cause a crash in the event that that newDB is null.

Comment: This has stopped the app from crashing, but the listview will not populate with data.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this line `newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();` if throwing exception.

In turn the `finally` block is called where you are missing the '{' and '}' for your `if` statement.

So you will get uncought `NullPointerException` on `newDB.close();` because newDB is null and app will crash...

Update log in catch block to `Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database", se);` and check the LogCat for more information about what went wrong.